# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing self in recursive function defined in an extension

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am experiencing unexpected EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors when accessing `self` within a recursive function defined in an extension.

I have reduced the complexity of my set-up to a simple(ish) example which still demonstrates the issue. I have a `ThemeableViewController` protocol, and a protocol extension which defines one function implementation (`cascaseInitialise(withTheme)`):

```
protocol ThemeableViewController where Self: UIViewController { }

extension ThemeableViewController {
    func cascadeInitialise(withTheme theme: Theme) {

        // will perform other initialisation here; excluded for testing

        if let tabVC = self as? UITabBarController, let innerVCs = tabVC.viewControllers {
            for themableVC in innerVCs.flatMap({$0 as? ThemeableViewController}) {
                themableVC.cascadeInitialise(withTheme: theme)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have used extensions to make other `UIViewController` classes conform to this protocol:

```
extension UITabBarController: ThemeableViewController { }

extension UISplitViewController: ThemeableViewController { }
```

My root view controller is a `UITabBarController`; its 4 view controllers are all `UISplitViewController`s. I call `cascadeInitialise` on my root view controller as follows:

```
let rootTabBarVC = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
rootTabBarVC.cascadeInitialise(withTheme: .normal)
```

In the *second* call of `cascadeInitialise` (i.e. when `self` is a `UISplitViewController`), I observe a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on the line starting `if let tabVC`. See the following stack trace:

[image]

The strange thing is that when debugging, if I put a breakpoint on that line, entering `po self as? UITabBarController` in the console does *not* cause an error (it returns, as expected, `nil`):

[image: Xcode debugger; crash]

[image]

I can't work out what the issue here is.

Comment: show us how you call `cascade ...`

Comment: The crash could be a compiler bug but why are you even detecting the type instead of putting the implementation directly to extension of `UITabBarController`?

Comment: @LouFranco I've added the call to `cascadeInitialise` to the question. I'm getting the app's root view controller from the `window` on the app delegate.

Comment: @Sulthan there were originally a bunch of other types I was handling (`UISplitViewController`, `UINavigationController`, etc). I did originally have a protocol method to return "child VCs", which would be implemented by all classes conforming to the protocol and then used in `cascade...`. I've simplified things in order to make the question simpler.

Comment: if the 2nd call crashes, that's the one we need to see.

Comment: By "second call", I mean the the execution of the function the first time it is called recursively. Sorry, kind of hard to explain. I'll add the stack trace to the question soon